# C# BeginInvoke problem

Tags: c#, wpf

Why does i have this error and how to fix it. Thanks for help

Error   4   Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

```
    void provider_GetAssignmentsComplete(object sender, QP_Truck_Model.Providers.GetAssignmentsEventArgs e) {
        lvMyAssignments.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            lvMyAssignments.ItemsSource = e.HandOverDocs;
        });
    }
```

Comment: It's better to use `Task` scheduling or `SynchronizationContext` rather than `Dispatcher`, so that your BLL code is not tied to WPF/Silverlight.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lambda expression are not implicitly convertible to delegates in certain cases. Specifically, if the method expects the type `Delegate` you have to first explicitly cast the lambda for the compiler to accept it.

What you can do is explicitly cast the lambda, which should allow you to use `BeginInvoke`:

```
lvMyAssignments.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( (Action)(() => 
        { 
            lvMyAssignments.ItemsSource = e.HandOverDocs; 
        }));
```

Normally, if you have a method with a strongly-typed delegate signature, like:

```
public static void BeginInvoke( Action d ) { ... }
```

The compiler can convert a lambda expression to the appropriate delegate signature needed. But if the method is loosely typed:

```
public static void BeginInvoke( Delegate d ) { ... }
```

the compiler will not accept a lambda. You can, however, cast the lambda expression to a specific delegate signature (say Action), and then pass that to the method. The compiler cannot automatically do this for you, because there are many different delegate types that could be a valid match for the signature of the lambda ... and the compiler has no way of knowing which would be the right one.

Answer (score 3):

Cast it to a Delegate object, such as `Action`

```
lvMyAssignments.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => lvMyAssignments.ItemsSource = e.HandOverDocs)));
```